# installing SDL on fedora

Tags: sdl, fedora

I installed FEDORA and SDL and wish to program graphics in C. on compilation, I am getting lot of undefined references to SDL_MapRGB, SDL_Init etc
I searched the file system SDL.dll is missing..

how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Linux does not use .dll files for storing libraries, but .so.

Anyhow, to install SDL in fedora:

```
sudo yum install SDL*
```

This will install the complete SDL library with associated devel packages.

You will also probably want to install the Development Tools group of packages (for gcc and other build tools):

```
sudo yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
```

When compiling, you will need to tell GCC which library to link:

```
gcc mycoolapp.c -o myapp -lSDL -lSDL_mixer
```

Comment: I have followed the first instruction and installed SDL.. it didn't help..  I am following the second instruction now and some 73 installations are in progress. will see if that helps or not. in the meantime, could you enlighten me about the root cause of the problem? out of my little knowledge of programming, I feel that some functions are not getting linked? is it so?

Comment: second suggestion also failed to solve the issue... any more ideas?

Comment: Well, fedora does not have the development environment setup by default. Installing the Development Tools group will at least get you valgrind, gcc, gdb and many others. How are you referencing the SDL libraries in your c application? You might also need to pass GCC flags.

Comment: Currently there's SDL and SDL2 packages available. Do they interfere (installing both SDL-devel and SDL2-devel)?

Comment: @moooeeeep Installing both SDL and SDL2 should not interfere at the package level. You will only be able to link your application to one of the SDL library (SDL or SDL2). See http://wiki.libsdl.org/MigrationGuide