# Where to get SDL2 non-default libraries for Fedora 19?

Tags: c++, sdl, fedora, sdl-2

So the basic SDL2 development libraries are within the repositories and easily accessed with yum, but what about the other SDL based libraries? I'm talking about SDL2_image or SDL2_mixer etc. Is there any way to get and use those? Fallowing the instructions from a post on stack overflow ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102313/installing-sdl-on-fedora)), they seem to be downloaded but are they SDL2? Or are they SDL 1.2? It would be really nice to know where to get SDL2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPD** as for SDL2_image, you can now install it with

$ sudo yum install SDL2_image

<s>You can't install them from repos *yet*. I've just talked with SDL2 (co)maintainer, Igor Gnatenko, and he is willing to add these packages to Fedora repositories. So please wait a few days more</s>.

Answer (score 0):

```
yum install SDL_image* SDL_mixer*
```

This will include libraries and the devel package.